# Probability of non red OR non face card using direct method

Tags: probability

> Probability of non red OR non face card using direct method

I know the complement is the way to approach this problem, but I'm trying to visualize it with the direct method.

I was thinking:

$\begin{align*}P(R' \cup F') &= P(R') + P(F') - P(R'\cap F')\\ 
&=\frac{26}{52}+\frac{40}{52}-\frac{20}{52} \end{align*}$

I keep seeing $P(R' \cap F')$ as " black and numbered cards" but I know it's wrong...

Would $P(R' \cap F')$ be $\frac{26}{52}+\frac{40}{52}-\frac{20}{52}=\frac{46}{52}$ ? That would give us the right answer $\frac{5}{13}$ ?

Comment: How is $\frac{46}{52} = \frac5{13}$

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion... $\frac{46}{52}$ would be the intersection and $\frac{5}{13}$ is the answer to the question.

Comment: What is the exact question, to start with ?

Comment: In the title: Probability of drawing a non red OR a non faced card

Comment: Then the only part left out is red faced, isn't it ?

Comment: To be honest it's not completely clear in my mind... I'm trying to visualize it with the formula... the only part left out for the intersection you mean?

Answer (score 1):

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ Red $\,\,\,$Black
Face $\quad\quad 6 \quad\quad 6$
Non-face $\; 20 \quad 20$

You should be able to visualize now, and proceed onwards

Comment: That makes sense, but then we're left with $\frac{20}{52}$ as $P(R' \cap F')$ and it doesn't work with the formula ? I mustn't be doing it the right way...

Comment: If you can clearly see from the table what the correct answer should be, then any other ans must be wrong !

Comment: I understand... and we know what the right answer is. I was really just looking to solve the problem without using the complement (ie. direct method). I don't understand why the formula doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As you can directly see, $P(R'\cup F') = \frac{46}{52}$. So either the question you give is wrong, or the book answer is wrong !

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The question being « What is the probability that the card drawn is not red or not a face »  had me seeing it as $P(R' \cup F')$ but the textbook wanted us to see it as $P(R \cup F)'$ which of course is not the same and can, in my view, lead to confusion (because of how the question is written). But I appreciate your help.